# How to change django to save password using MD5?

Tags: django, authentication

Hello I`ll try to change the default SHA encrypt system to MD5 in django.

I know.. SHA is better then MD5, but I NEED to use MD5.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting in your settings:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
)
```

This will store the passwords as:

```
algorithm$hash
```

And will use a salt.

If you need something different you'll need to code your own hasher. Shouldn't be hard, take a look at Django MD5 implementation: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L329

Comment: Awesome. Glad it was useful.